# Jenkins FStrigger dynamic file lookup

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

i am trying to schedule a trigger for the following patter:

```
/mnt/YYYY-MM-DD/DONE
```

for example one of the following lines will trigger:

```
/mnt/2018-12-18/DONE
/mnt/2017-12-18/DONE
```

i tried to put the patterns( with Schedule of H/2 * * * *)

```
/mnt/2*/DONE
/mnt/2**/DONE
```

but the jenkins did not trigger

with the reason:

```
Polling started on Dec 20, 2018 5:12:00 PM
Polling for the job data_Import
Looking nodes where the poll can be run.
Looking for a candidate node to run the poll.
Trying to find an eligible node with the assigned project label server1

Polling remotely on server1
The folder path '/mnt/2**' doesn't exist.
The computed file doesn't exist.

Polling complete. Took 16 ms.
No changes.
```